# Facebook connection serialization

Tags: serialization, connection, spring-social-facebook

I've written an app based on spring-social-facebook that has a long running process. To avoid timeout issues and scalability issues; the information needed by the long running process is bundled into a serializable object; to be passed to a worker process via RabitMQ.

I'm using API version 2.5 and spring-social-facebook version 2.0.3.RELEASE.

Can someone recommend an approach for accomplishing this?

Seems like getting the necessary info from the FacebookTemplate in the web tier; passing it in a serializable object; then reconstituting it in the worker process would work.

However, I don't see methods for getting the info needed to construct a FacebookTemplate instance.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. The Facebook / FacebookTemplate will not serialize... I get this error when attempting it: Cannot deserialize BeanFactory with id application: no factory registered for this id

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Your title sounds like you're trying to serialize a socket connection. You can't do that.

Comment: No that is not what this issue is about. I know sockets can't be serialized and I also know that sockets are not used directly by Spring Social. What I want to do is get information from the FacebookTemplate object, more accurately the accessToken. I found a way to do this by calling the createData method on the Connection object; which means I can remove the hack that I used to accomplish this. This may be useful info for someone; since it does require searching the API a bit to find it. Get the connection from the ConnectionRepository class...